# Formatting equations for linprog in MATLAB

Tags: matlab, linear-programming

I have to solve a simple problem using function `linprog` in matlab math toolbox. The problem is that I don't know how to format my equations so this function solves the problem.

This is the function I am trying to minimize (`a_i` are some given coefficients, `x` is in R^5):

```
x = argmax min{a1*x1 + a2*x2, a2*x2 + a3*x3 + a4*x4, a4*x4 + a5*x5}
```

subject to:

```
sum(x_i) = 3000
all x_i >= 0
```

This could be rephrased as:

```
(x, lambda) = argmin(-lambda)
```

subject to:

```
a1*x1 + a2*x2 >= lambda
a2*x2 + a3*x3 + a4*x4 >= lambda
a4*x4 + a5*x5 >= lambda
sum(x_i) = 3000
all x_i >= 0
```

I could only find examples of minimization of simple linear functions without min/max arguments in it. Could you give me a hint how to make my structures as arguments for `linprog` function?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let's try the following
your `x` vector is now

```
[x1 x2 x3 x4 x5 lambda]
```

the objective vector

```
f = [0 0 0 0 0 -1]
```

equality constraint:

```
Aeq = [1 1 1 1 1 0] beq = 3000
```

Inequality constraint:

```
A = [-a1 -a2 0 0 0  1; 0 -a2 -a3 -a4 0 1; 0 0 0 -a4 -a5 1] b = [0;0;0]
```

lower bound:

```
lb = [0 0 0 0 0 -inf]
```

now try

> linprog( f, A, b, Aeq, beq, lb )

up to some transposing of arguments should do the trick.

Answer (score 1):

I don't believe you can pose the question as you phrased it as a linprog problem.  The "MIN" operation is the problem.  Since the objective function can't be phrased as

```
y = f'x.
```

Even though your constraints are linear, your objective function isn't.

Maybe with some trickery you can linearize it.  But if so, that's a math problem.  See: https://math.stackexchange.com/

Comment: My response here is incorrect, see the expanded "This could be rephrased as" part of the question for a technique to map the non-linear objective into a linear objective function